# Upload binary file to GAE Python Blobstore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore, webapp2

I can upload text files (.csv, .json) with this code, but I can't upload an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx).

```
class CreateTeam(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler, BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/create_team')
        context = {'upload_url': upload_url}
        self.render('create_team.html', **context)

    def post(self):
        blob_info = self.get_uploads('file')[0]
        blob_key = blob_info.key()
        blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key)
        file_data = blob_reader.read()  # this line stalls out
        blobstore.delete(blob_key())
        self.redirect('/')
```

When I try even a one-line .xls file, the blob_reader.read() line locks up on my Mac.  In my browser (Chrome), the tab icon seems to spin forever and the GAE Launcher freezes up.  I have to quit it and start over.

My html looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action={{ upload_url }} enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <p>Upload the file</p>
        <input type="file" name="file">
    </div>
</form>
```

Do binary files get handled differently for uploads?  My form above is over-simplified.  I have other form elements that are posted at the same time.

Comment: What is the file size of this binary file?  Try: `blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key, buffer_size=2000000)`.  Can you log the blob_key just before this line?

Comment: And this is not right: `blobstore.delete(blob_key())`.  Should be `blobstore.delete(blob_key)`.

Comment: @GAEfan Yeah, that delete key syntax is wrong.  I actually muffed up the paste job here.  That's not a problem in my real code.  What I can say is that your feedback gave me the confidence to go attack this again and I finally licked this thing.  In my code, I had a `logging.info` statement immediately before and after the `blob_reader.read()` line.  It was the logging line that was hanging.  Pretty disheartening that the line that I was using to debug was the culprit.  But I sure am glad to be past this one.